# CoreData - usage of backgroundContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to understand a concept of backgroundContext in CoreData. Though I read several articles about it, I am not still sure about its purpose.

I have an app using CoreData that allows user create, update or delete records. User can also fetch the data he added. I want to ensure that if there are a lot of records, it will not influence a flow of the UI while fetching data.

So I studied a bit about backgroundContexts. I implemented following according to what I understood. I am not sure though whether it is a correct solution. My idea is - if I fetch in background, it cannot influence the main thread.

```
//I have an PersistentContainer created by Xcode.

//I create an backgroundContext.
self.backContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

//Then if the user adds a new record, it's added to backContext and saved to mainContext
...
let newRecord = Record(context: self.backContext!)
...
self.backContext!.save()
self.context!.save() // mainContext
...

//If the user fetches the data I use:
self.backContext.perform {
...
}

//Since I want to show results in UI, I know these objects (from fetch) exist just in the background thread, so instead I fetch for IDs 
.resultType = .managedObjectIDResultType

//Now I have IDs of fetched objects, so I restore objects in main thread using their IDs:
let object = try? self.backContext.existingObject(with: ID) as? Record

//and I can finally use fetched objects to update UI.
```

The question is:

- Is this even correct what I am doing? (it works perfectly though)
- Will this solve the problem of freezing UI if user fetches a large amount of data?

How do we use backgroundContexts correctly? Why is it not recommended to work directly with mainContext? How to prevent freezing UI while fetching big data?

One more question: If I use FetchedResultsConteroller - do I need to handle the problem of freezing UI? (while waiting on first (init) fetch result?)

Of course I am ignoring that while fetching data, my context is blocked, so I cannot create a new record

Comment: When you say "Fetching", do you mean fetching objects using fetch requests, or fetching data from an API and making the response into core data objects?

Comment: Fetching objects using fetch requests (fetch NSManagedObject)

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching objects to be displayed on screen, you should absolutely be using fetch requests against the main thread context. Core Data is designed for this specific use case and you should not be experiencing slowdowns or freezes because of executing fetches. If you are having problems, then profile your app in instruments and find out where the actual slowdown is.

Background contexts are meant to be used if you are performing bulky or long-running work like processing large API responses which you've shown to be affecting main thread performance.

> So I do not have to be afraid of freezing UI, even if my database will contain thousands of records? I can make fetch request with mainContext?

Yes

> If I would like to do some special time consuming operations that would not be shown to UI, my code would be correct, right?

Yes, you'd normally create a background context, do work, save the background context - and then access those objects as normal from the main context.

> And last but not least - why is it not recommended to work directly with mainContext when I add a new record?

I'm not sure where you've seen this recommendation, but quite a common pattern is to make a new main-queue (*not* background) child context to support the application workflow of adding a new object. Then if the user cancels the addition, you can just discard the editing context without needing to worry about undoing your work.

Comment: Thanks! So I do not have to be afraid of freezing UI, even if my database will contain thousands of records? I can make fetch request with mainContext? 
If I would like to do some special time consuming operations that would not be shown to UI, my code would be correct, right? (excluding the part of .managedObjectIDResultType)
And last but not least - why is it not recommended to work directly with mainContext when I add a new record? May I add new record directly to mainContext and do not care about it? Thanks a lot in advance!